# SQL nested loops

Tags: sql, nested-loops

I have a problem, I have added a column to one of my database tables and now i need to populate this column with data.

Here are the tables:

**Table QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS**
with columns:

```
ID,
QUESTION_NUMBER,
PARENT_QUESTION_ID,
PARENT_QUESTIONNAIRE_ID,
QUESTION_CODE
```

**Table QUESTIONNAIRE**
with columns:

```
ID,
INTRODUCTION
```

What I first need to do is to find all unique QUESTIONNAIRE.ID and for each of those I need to find all QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS.ID that have this id as PARENT_QUESTIONNAIRE_ID and set the QUESTION_CODE as QUESTION_CODE=QUESTION_NUMBER*100.

Then, before moving on to the next QUESTIONNAIRE_ID i need to find all QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS.ID that have the current QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS.ID as PARENT_QUESTION_ID and set the QUESTION_CODE as
QUESTION_CODE=(parents question_code)+'.'+QUESTION_CODE.QUESTION_NUMBER*100.

How to perform this, complicated, nested loop? Seems like I have to use several loops?

**Sample Data:**

```
QUESTIONNAIRES
ID
1869359
1876176


QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS
ID         QUESTION_NUMBER     PARENT_QUESTIONNAIRE_ID   PARENT_QUESTION_ID  QUESTION_CODE
1869360            1                   1869359                 null              null
1869362            2                   1869359                 null              null
1869364            3                   1869359                 null              null
1869367            1                    null                  1869364            null
1869369            1                   1876176                 null              null
1869371            2                   1876176                 null              null
1869372            3                   1876176                 null              null
1869374            4                   1876176                 null              null
1869377            1                    null                  1869372            null
```

And after i want it to look like this:

```
QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS
ID         QUESTION_NUMBER     PARENT_QUESTIONNAIRE_ID   PARENT_QUESTION_ID  QUESTION_CODE
1869360            1                   1869359                 null              100
1869362            2                   1869359                 null              200
1869364            3                   1869359                 null              300
1869367            1                    null                  1869364          300.100
1869368            1                    null                  1869367          300.100.100
1869369            2                    null                  1869367          300.100.200
1869370            1                   1876176                 null              100
1869371            2                   1876176                 null              200
1869372            3                   1876176                 null              300
1869374            4                   1876176                 null              400
1869377            1                    null                  1869371          200.100
```

Note that it can be more levels of "child questions"
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: sample data provided!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS
SET QUESTION_CODE = (QUESTION_NUMBER * 100)
WHERE QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT QUESTIONNAIRE.ID
                                     FROM QUESTIONNAIRE, QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS
                                     WHERE QUESTIONNAIRE_QUESTIONS.ID = PARENT_QUESTION_ID)
```

Not so sure about the 2nd question. Is that a typo?`QUESTION_CODE.QUESTION_NUMBER*100`

Comment: Not a typo, see sample data above. Your example does not update the "child questions" with QUESTION_CODE like "300.100"